# numba gives error when reshaping numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am trying to optimize some code which has some loops and matrix operations. However, I am running into some errors. Please find the code and output below.

Code:

```py
@njit
def list_of_distance(d1): #d1 was declared as List()
    list_of_dis = List()
    for k in range(len(d1)):
        sum_dist = List()
        for j in range(3):
            s = np.sum(square(np.reshape(d1[k][:,:,j].copy(),d1[k][:,:,j].shape[0]*d1[k][:,:,j].shape[1]))) 
            sum_dist.append(s) # square each value in the resulting list (dimenstion)   
        distance = np.sum(sum_dist) # adding the total value for each dimension to a list
        list_of_dis.append(np.round(np.sqrt(distance)))  # Sum the values to get the total squared values of residual images 

    return list_of_dis
```

Output:

```py
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<function sum at 0x7f898814bd08>) with argument(s) of type(s): (list(int64))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<function sum at 0x7f898814bd08>)
[2] During: typing of call at <ipython-input-18-8c787cc8deda> (7)


File "<ipython-input-18-8c787cc8deda>", line 7:
def list_of_distance(d1):
    <source elided>
        for j in range(3):
            s = np.sum(square(np.reshape(d1[k][:,:,j].copy(),d1[k][:,:,j].shape[0]*d1[k][:,:,j].shape[1]))) 
            ^

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

Would anyone be able to help me out regarding this issue.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Comment: Can you supply sample data for what d1 contains? Also, we’re you able to run this code without Numba?

Comment: Hi @Ethan, thanks for the reply. d1 contains a list of RGB images. Yes it worked perfectly with normal python code. However, it ran pretty slow hence, the effort to optimize the code. The kernel also restarted after two loops. For which, I also do not know the reason why. Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to get this to work and mocked up "d1", but this does work for me with Numba. This main issue that caused the runtime error appears to be that np.sum does not work on list with Numba, although it did run correctly when I commented out @jit. wrapping sumdist with np.array() resolves this issue.

```
d1 = [np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3), np.arange(27,54).reshape(3,3,3)]

@njit
def list_of_distance(d1): #d1 was declared as List()
    list_of_dis = [] #List() Changed - would not compile
    for k in range(len(d1)):
        sum_dist = [] #List() #List() Changed - would not compile
        for j in range(3):
            s = np.sum(np.square(np.reshape(d1[k][:,:,j].copy(),d1[k][:,:,j].shape[0]*d1[k][:,:,j].shape[1]))) #Added np. to "square"
            sum_dist.append(s) # square each value in the resulting list (dimenstion)   
        distance = np.sum(np.array(sum_dist)) # adding the total value for each dimension to a list - Wrapped list in np.array
        list_of_dis.append(np.round(np.sqrt(distance)))  # Sum the values to get the total squared values of residual images 

    return list_of_dis

list_of_distance(d1)
Out[11]: [79.0, 212.0]
```